# C# trivia game: What to do in case of a tie?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm currently working on a trivia game. I have written a Team class, a Question class and a Round class.

This is my Team class (I wont post properties, constructors, and methods since they are not relevant to my question).

```
public class Team
{
    private int _teamNumber = 0;
    private int _score = 0;
}
```

And this is my Round class:

```
public class Round
{
    Team[] _teams = new Team[4];
    Question[] _questions = new Clue[30];
    bool _done = true; 
}
```

The problem I'm having is what to do in case of a tie. There are 8 teams. Two winners from each of the first two Rounds (4 teams each) will qualify for the 3rd and final round.

So in case something like this happens:

```
currentRound.Teams[0].Score = 300;
currentRound.Teams[1].Score = 300;
currentRound.Teams[2].Score = 100;
currentRound.Teams[3].Score = 350;
```

As you can see there's a tie for the 2nd place.

I know I can check for repeats, but what if the teams have scores like

500, 400, 200, 200

or

500, 500, 200, 100

In this case there is no need for a tie break, since only the top two teams advance to the next round.

So i was wondering if anyone can help me come up with an algorithm that can help determine if I need a tie-Breaker round or not. And if I do, which teams should we pick and finally what are the top two teams from each round.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is your data source SQL?  If so it has a really handy [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) function that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using LINQ to determine if there are any teams that are tied for second?

```
var orderedResults = currentRound.Teams.OrderBy(x=>x.Score).ToList();
if(orderedResults.Any(x=>x.Score == orderedResults[1].Score))
    var team2 = RunTieBreaker(
        orderedResults.Where(x=>x.Score == orderedResults[1].Score).ToList());
```

You could probably even remove the if and just do the RunTieBreaker if you use this implementation:

```
Team RunTieBreaker(List<Team> teamsToTieBreak)
{
    if(teamsToTieBreak.Count == 1)
        return teamsToTieBreak[0];
    //Do tiebreaker
}
```

Alternatively, you could do an `OrderBy` and `Take(2)`. Then you could run the `Where` and/or `Any` against the 2nd team.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var result = currentRound.Teams.OrderBy(t => t.Score).GroupBy(t => t.Score).Take(2);
if (result.Sum(m => m.Count()) > 2)
{
    //Need extra round
}
else
{
    //No extra round
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like to have in my program to always make sure that it is impossible to have tie. so like if it was a coin tossing game I would always have a odd number of throws. With something like this you might could incorporate time, or you could add in bonus points for say accuracy. Or you could have a list of most answers answered correctly in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Order the teams by score and take the second element. Take only teams that have a score greater or equal to that score. If you get more than 2 teams - all the teams that have a score equal to that score go to the tie breaker.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Team> n = [total teams in round];
int x = [number moving to next round];

OrderTeamsByScore(n);
// get participants by score uses value of x to determine whether tie-break is needed
Team p = RunTieBreaker(GetTeamsByScore(n[x-1].Score, x)); //zero based array
```

Note:If only 1 Team has the score "n[x-1].Score" then it will win the tie break by default; If tie break not needed it will return "n[x-1]" by default

Answer (score 0):

Get the lowest score above the qualifying line, and count how many teams have that score or higher:

```
int qualifyingCount = 2;
int score =
  currentRound.Teams.Select(t => t.Score)
  .OrderByDescending(s => s)
  .Take(qualifyingCount).Last();

if (currentRound.Teams.Count(t => t.Score >= score) > qualifyingCount) {
  // tie break needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps and you'll get a list of winers and a list of tied teams. **With these two lists you can answer your three questions.**

**1)** Order by score. 
**2)** Identify tied team's score. If there isn't a tie, set -1.
**3)** Get list of non tied winers. If everyone is tied, this list is empty.
**4)** Get list of tied teams. If there isn't a tie, this list is empty.
**5)** Check winers, whether there is a tie or whatever you need.

```
var orderedTeams = currentRound.Teams.OrderBy(t => t.Score).ToList();
int tieScore = orderedTeams[1].Score == orderedTeams[2].Score ? orderedTeams[1].Score : -1;
List<Team> winers = tieScore > 0 ? orderedTeams.Where(t => t.Score > tieScore) : orderedTeams.Take(2).ToList();
List<Team> tiedTeams = orderedTeams.Where(t => t.Score == tieScore).ToList();
bool needTieBreak = tiedTeams.Count > 0;
```